# What is the use of F12 key in Mozilla Firefox?

Tags: firefox, keyboard-shortcuts

I think it is used to check the coding but when I tried it didn't respond. I mean it doesn't give any response and showing the data of current website.

Answer (score 4):

<kbd>F12</kbd> opens the built in Firefox Developer Tools in recent versions of Firefox. Press <kbd>F12</kbd> again to close it. There is an extension to turn off the shortcut: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/disable-f12-shortcut/

Answer (score 2):

The f12 is a shortcut to Open up [firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firebug/) in firefox. To open up firebug you must firstly have it installed

Answer (score 2):

F12 is a standard Firefox shortcut that toggles the 'Firefox Developer Tools' on and off. 
When you hit F12, Firefox's bottom half opens to show/reveal it's 'Developer Tools,' a Web Console (toolbox?), which

1. Logs information associated with a web page: network requests, JavaScript, CSS, security errors and warnings as well as error, warning and informational messages logged by JavaScript code running in the page.
2. Enables you to interact with a web page by executing JavaScript expressions in the context of the page.

It also has an inspector, a debugger, style editor, a profiler and more.

Again, F12 toggles it on and off.

Go to ≡ > Web Developer and you can see the menu of all it does and their shortcuts.

*(Firebug* was *a free open-source web extension for Firefox that facilitated the live debugging, editing, and monitoring of any website's CSS, HTML, DOM, XHR, and JavaScript. 
It was deprecated (replaced by something better) in favor of the integrated developer tools (F12) added to Firefox itself. As Firefox 57 no longer supports XUL add-ons, Firebug is no longer compatible.)*

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>F12</kbd> is not bound to anything in Firefox - see [Keyboard shortcuts](http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/keyboard-shortcuts-perform-firefox-tasks-quickly). You are probably thinking of the [Firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firebug/) addon which opens with that key.

The built-in [Page Inspector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Page_Inspector) in Firefox (v10 onwards) is accessed with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> and then <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

In newer versions of Firefox (I have 91.12.0esr), there is an
"experimental" setting in the `about:config` configuration page that can disable the F12 hotkey (https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1630228)

Setting the `devtools.experiment.f12.shortcut_disabled` key to `true` causes the F12 key to bring up a temporary text box that says "To use the F12 shortcut, first open DevTools via the Web Developer menu." but thankfully no longer opens the DevTools bar.

This should be the default behavior, IMHO, since only a small fraction of users will know or care about viewing the HTML source of the page.